# Date is not written in my DB

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a hidden input where its supposed to send the current date to its respective place in the database:

```
<input type="hidden" name="DATE" value="<?php echo date("Y/m/d"); ?> />
```

As we all know, the date() function returns the *server* date and not the user's, so I changed the timezone:

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$MexDate = date("Y/m/d");  ?>
```

Then, I changed the value of the hidden input, so know I could send the current date according to Mexico's timezone.

```
<input type="hidden" name="DATE" value="<?php echo $MexDate; ?>" />
```

The problem here is that insted of writing the date, it writes nothing (0000-00-00). That didn't happen when I was using just `date()` without changing the timezone. What happened here?

Comment: Changing the date in PHP will still not give you the client datetime - you could update the hidden input using javascript though if you were after the date/time for the user

Comment: Make you have set sql_mode in mysql conf so that you can not insert zero dates. You likely don't want the insert to fail silently and discover that data is corrupt after a few days. You can set this using sql_mode='NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE'. There are some other options you should seriously consider setting: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you haven't specified the right format. I'd suggest you specify the format as Y-m-d instead of Y/m/d

```
$MexDate = date("Y-m-d");
```

Also, another way would be using mysql NOW() function. It will insert the current date in the database.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I already did that. Does NOW() returns the user's date or server's?

Comment: `$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO CCM (NJuzgado, Sec, Expediente, Actor, Demandado, CLIENTFLAG, Link, Flag, DATE) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, date)",`

Answer (score 0):

Once you change the TimeZone through through php. if you check this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//time-zone-support.html it says

```
Per-connection time zones. Each client that connects has its own time zone setting, given by the session time_zone variable. Initially, the session variable takes its value from the global time_zone variable, but the client can change its own time zone with this statement:
```

Therefore you need to set the same timezone in mysql also and that can be done through this command.
Suppose $db is your mysql object then use

```
$now = new DateTime();
$mins = $now->getOffset() / 60;
$sgn = ($mins < 0 ? -1 : 1);
$mins = abs($mins);
$hrs = floor($mins / 60);
$mins -= $hrs * 60;
$offset = sprintf('%+d:%02d', $hrs*$sgn, $mins);
$db->query("SET time_zone = '$offset'");
```

Got this from https://www.sitepoint.com/synchronize-php-mysql-timezone-configuration/